# Remove all the words in a string that are in round brackets in java?

Tags: java, string

The input is `a (good) example((eo)--)e)`. I have used an iterative way.

I tried with the following code:

```
public String scartaParentesi(String s)
{   

    ups = s.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", "");
    return ups;
}
```

The output of this code is `a  example(--)e)`.

The expected output is `a examplee)`.

Comment: Why the output is not "a example)" or "a examplee)"? as there is an extra ')'

Comment: what is the output of "x(y"?

Comment: Sorry i put an extra ')', the input is "a (good) example((eo)--)e", that must return "a example".

Comment: Why not "a examplee"?

Comment: there's an 'e' in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on description and comments, you can do:

```
    String str = "a (good) example((eo)--)e";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int openedParenthesesCount = 0;
    
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(') {
            openedParenthesesCount++;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            openedParenthesesCount--;
        } else if (openedParenthesesCount == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(c);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
```

Output:

```
a  examplee
```

Assumption - number of '(' equals to number of ')'.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution without any assumptions of the number of opening and closing braces:

```
String text = "a (good) example((eo)--)e)";
StringBuilder outText = new StringBuilder();
Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();

int i=0;
while (i<text.length()) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == '(') {
        stack.addFirst(text.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        if (text.charAt(i) != ')') {
            stack.addFirst(text.charAt(i));
            i++;
        } else {
            if (stack.removeFirst() == '(') {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    outText.append(text.charAt(i));
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
before: a (good) example((eo)--)e)
after: a  examplee)
```

You can also use your original String replaceAll method by putting it on a loop, replacing the same pattern on the last updated string. The break condition of the loop will be checking if 2 consecutive iterations output the same string, i.e. no pattern to replace:

```
String prev = text.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", "");
while (!text.equals(prev)) {
    prev = text;
    text = text.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", "");
}
System.out.println("after2: " + text);
```